# Using new on same veriable without using delete- c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I've got a lill question.

Can I use the new function to allocate memory to the same veriable without using delete?

example:

```
int *a;
int size1 = 2, size2 = 4;
a = new int[size1];
a = new int[size2]; //without using delete before
```

does new works like realloc in c?

Why all the down votes?

Whats wrong with my question....?

Comment: It's a memory leak.

Comment: "does new works like realloc in c" - no.

Comment: The variable itself does not matter, but the pointer you got from new[] must be paired with a delete[], or it's a memory leak.

Comment: So, in case I do it like that, I am supposed to get an error while the program runs, no?

Comment: No, it should not give an error.  You should just run out of memory at some point if you keep doing that.

Comment: "So, in case I do it like that, I am supposed to get an error while the program runs, no?" - no.

Comment: No, no error. Unless you run valgrind or something.

Comment: No error but memory leaks.

Comment: Sure, you can do it - if you don't mind memory leaks. No, it is *not* equivalent to `realloc`. Just ditch all the manual memory management already and use proper containers like `std::vector` - and if you really *have to* then at least use smart pointers. In modern C++, seeing `new` and (especially) `delete` invoked directly is a "code smell" unless you are in some very special corner.

Comment: Alright, I understand. Thank you very much guys

Comment: _Why all the down votes? Whats wrong with my question....?_ Lack of research, mostly.

Comment: Use smart pointers, done deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The operator `new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/)  allocates size bytes of storage, suitably aligned to represent any object of that size, and returns a pointer to the first byte of this block. [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr.

In your case, the first call on `new[]` operator creates a block, and then stores a pointer to it in variable `a`. The second call on `new[]` creates another block, and then stores the pointer to it in variable `a`. The block created from the first call is not destroyed.

If `realloc` is called, the existing block is resized and may be moved if needed. If the block is moved, the space allocated for the old block is freed.